# Get printer product and device id

Tags: python, escpos

I need help finding the device id and product id for my printer, these specifications are required in this printing library for printers with ESCPOS support found here.

[Library](https://github.com/shantanubhadoria/python-printer-escpos)

This is what I have when I follow instructions for getting product and vendor ids in the properties tab

[image: Example]

Clarify

1. How do I find exact product and vendor ids
2. What are usb input and output endpoints and where can they be found?

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time and include the name of the library in the post. Also, it might help if you [edit] your question to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a tool here that enables you to view the specs for all USB devices in the system

[NirSoft USB viewer tool](http://C:%5CUsers%5CJohn%5CDesktop%5C2020-11-17%2007_43_58-Window.png)